# Catch a client close connection from inside a Apache module

Tags: c, apache, api, module

I'm developing a apache module in C. This module performs a processing that can take "long" time. During this processing how I can receive and manage a signal (because i think is related to signals) that the client has closed the connection? And stop the useless processing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is too broad, but --- how about threads? Have a main thread for messages, et cetera, and a worker thread for the processing. In the worker thread, check every once in a while (say, every iteration; or every 10 iterations; or every N seconds --- depending on the type of processing) if an exit has been requested.